# Google API Directions Service, converting to meters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Directions Service to calculate the distance between two addresses that uses address lookup, it all appears to be working fine, the only issue I am having is if you search as an example the same pickup and destination, it is returning 12m (meters) instead of in km and therefore it's giving me the wrong calculations for very short journeys where it returns values in meters.

Is there a way I can make it only send KM?

(also, not sure if it is possible to get value in Miles as at the moment I am converting it from KM)

Here is the code:-

```
var location1;
var location2;

var address1;
var address2;

var latlng;
var geocoder;
var map;

var distance;

// finds the coordinates for the two locations and calls the showMap() function
function initialize()
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // creating a new geocode object

    // getting the two address values
    address1 = document.getElementById("pstreet").value;
    address2 = document.getElementById("dstreet").value;

    // finding out the coordinates
    if (geocoder) 
    {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address1}, function(results, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                //location of first address (latitude + longitude)
                location1 = results[0].geometry.location;
            } else 
            {
                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address2}, function(results, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                //location of second address (latitude + longitude)
                location2 = results[0].geometry.location;
                // calling the showMap() function to create and show the map 
                showMap();
            } else 
            {
                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}

// creates and shows the map
function showMap()
{
    // center of the map (compute the mean value between the two locations)
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng((location1.lat()+location2.lat())/2,(location1.lng()+location2.lng())/2);

    // set map options
        // set zoom level
        // set center
        // map type
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 1,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    // create a new map object
        // set the div id where it will be shown
        // set the map options
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    // show route between the points
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
    {
        suppressMarkers: true,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    var request = {
        origin:location1, 
        destination:location2,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
        {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
            console.log(distance);
            distance_KM = distance.slice(0, -2); // remove KM from kilometers to get KM int
            nearest_KM = Math.round(distance_KM);

            // Convert kilometers into mileage
            var km = parseFloat(nearest_KM);
            var mi = "";
            if (!isNaN(km)) mi = km * 0.621371192;

            distance_MI = Math.round(mi);

            $('#mileage').html(distance_MI);

            driving_time = "Aproximative driving time is: "+response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
            $('#time').html(driving_time);

        }
    });

    // compute distance between the two points
    var R = 6371; 
    var dLat = toRad(location2.lat()-location1.lat());
    var dLon = toRad(location2.lng()-location1.lng()); 

    var dLat1 = toRad(location1.lat());
    var dLat2 = toRad(location2.lat());

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(dLat1) * Math.cos(dLat1) * 
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;

}

function toRad(deg) 
{
    return deg * Math.PI/180;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
```

Use:

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
```

That is **always** in meters.

```
distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value; // meters
distance_KM = distance / 1000; // convert to kilometers
```

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Distance)

> **google.maps.Distance object specification**
>
> A representation of distance as a numeric value and a display string.
>
> **Properties**
>
> ---
>
> **value** | Type:  number
>
> **The distance in meters.**

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qnhpvk45/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var location1;
var location2;

var address1;
var address2;

var latlng;
var geocoder;
var map;

var distance;

// finds the coordinates for the two locations and calls the showMap() function
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // creating a new geocode object

  // getting the two address values
  address1 = document.getElementById("pstreet").value;
  address2 = document.getElementById("dstreet").value;

  // finding out the coordinates
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address1
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //location of first address (latitude + longitude)
        location1 = results[0].geometry.location;
      } else {
        //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address2
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //location of second address (latitude + longitude)
        location2 = results[0].geometry.location;
        // calling the showMap() function to create and show the map 
        showMap();
      } else {
        //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}

// creates and shows the map
function showMap() {
  // center of the map (compute the mean value between the two locations)
  latlng = new google.maps.LatLng((location1.lat() + location2.lat()) / 2, (location1.lng() + location2.lng()) / 2);

  // set map options
  // set zoom level
  // set center
  // map type
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };

  // create a new map object
  // set the div id where it will be shown
  // set the map options
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  // show route between the points
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  var request = {
    origin: location1,
    destination: location2,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
      console.log(distance);
      distance_KM = distance / 1000; // remove KM from kilometers to get KM int
      nearest_KM = Math.round(distance_KM);

      // Convert kilometers into mileage
      var km = parseFloat(nearest_KM);
      var mi = "";
      if (!isNaN(km)) mi = km * 0.621371192;

      distance_MI = Math.round(mi);

      $('#mileage').html(distance_MI + " miles");

      driving_time = "Aproximative driving time is: " + response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
      $('#time').html(driving_time);

    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="pstreet" value="New York,NY" />
<input id="dstreet" value="Newark, NJ" />
<input type="button" onclick="initialize()" value="recalculate" />
<div id="mileage"></div>
<div id="time"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Nice thank you, then `distance *= 0.000621371192;` to convert to miles